# Setting the .htaccess MIME type to text/cache-manifest in XAMPP to view websites offline in HTML5

Tags: html

I've seen pretty much all the tutorials in the web about how to make your site viewable offline using the cache manifest and they all say something like this:

> A manifest file must be served with the mime-type text/cache-manifest.
>   You may need to add a custom file type to your web server or .htaccess
>   configuration.

But when I look at my XAMPP directory, there aren't any files named ".htaccess" in my xampp/htdocs folder. I did a search under the xampp/ directory and there's quite a lot of them, one in each folder below:

- xampp/htdocs/drupal
- xampp/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib
- xampp/phpMyAdmin/libraries
- xampp/htdocs/xampp/sqlite
- xampp/htdocs/forbidden
- xampp/phpMyAdmin/contrib

My partner here says I have to make that myself inside xampp/htdocs/nameOfTheFolderOfMyWebApp but I don't quite trust him since it didn't work. Help?

Comment: Thanks, DanC. I think I found a rather direct solution, though.

Look for the mime.types configuration file in your Apache installation--I found mine inside xampp/apache/conf. Then, add the line "text/cache-manifest manifest" & save. I have a feeling that the second occurrence of the word "manifest" represents the file extension of my manifest file, so if you're using .appcache or .cfm as I've seen in the other more updated tutorials, you might need to add "appcache" of "cfm," but heads up, I didn't actually try that.

Source: http://www.technetra.com/2009/08/17/countdown-html5-cache-version/

Answer (score 1):

This may help, at least for testing:

Since you are using PHP, you could create a PHP file named `themanifestfile.php` with this content:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/cache-manifest'); ?>CACHE MANIFEST

demoimages/clownfish.jpg
demoimages/clownfishsmall.jpg
demoimages/flowingrock.jpg
# THE REST OF YOUR OFFLINE FILES GO HERE
```

Then, in your html:

```
<html manifest="themanifestfile.php">
```

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but it may save you a lot of time fighting against apache configuration files if you only need to test your app.